# Как передать объект базы данных из Activity во Fragment

Tags: android

Я недавно начал осваивать Android и в своем приложении столкнулся с проблемой - не могу понять как передать объект базы данных из главной Activity во Fragment.
В главной Activity создается объект базы данных посредством DBHelper для последующего взаимодействия с этой базой для всех компонентов приложения. Далее, по моему замыслу, несколько фрагментов (каждый выполняя свою функцию в какой-то момент времени) должны периодически взаимодействовать с базой данных через этот объект: каждый фрагмент должен сам сделать connect к базе данных, выполнить необходимые действия и отсоединиться. При этом хочется, чтобы объект базы данных был один на всех, чтобы его не нужно было в каждом фрагменте создавать.
Но не пойму, как передать этот объект базы данных из главной Activity во фрагмент? Читал статьи, везде описывается на примере передачи строки с помощью методов putString. Но как передать объект базы данных, или вообще свой собственный объект? Нет метода типа putDB или что-то похожее.
Прошу помочь советами.

Answer (score 0):

Расширяйте `SQLiteAssetHelper` в отдельном классе:

```java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static DatabaseHelper instance;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    ...
}
```

Потом из Activity/Fragment:

```java
mDatabase = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
```

PS: рекомендую использовать Room для хранения данных локально.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!